# NestJS Graphql Fastify FastifyError: fastify-plugin: fastify-accepts - expected '3.x' fastify version, '4.6.0' is installed

Tags: nestjs, fastify

I'm following the NestJS documentation on how to set up a fastify/apollo server with nest but after adding fastify to main.ts I get this error:

```
FastifyError: fastify-plugin: fastify-accepts - expected '3.x' fastify version, '4.6.0' is installed
```

I've tried installing fastify 3.x, changing versions of other modules but according to yarn.lock some modules need 3.x and others need 4.x.

These are the docs I'm following:

1. https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/performance
2. https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/quick-start

Here is my main.ts

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import {
  FastifyAdapter,
  NestFastifyApplication,
} from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter({ logger: true }),
  );

  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  await app.listen(3000);
  console.log(`Application is running on: ${await app.getUrl()}`);
}
bootstrap();
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/apollo": "^10.1.0",
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/graphql": "^10.1.2",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-fastify": "^9.1.1",
    "apollo-server-fastify": "^3.10.2",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.0.1",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "ts-morph": "^16.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "28.1.8",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "28.1.3",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "28.0.8",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "4.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`@nestjs/common@^9` and `@nestjs/platform-fastify@^9` require you to use `fastify@^4`. However, `apllo-server-fastify` [does not support `fastify@^4`](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/6757) and will not until apollo-server v4 comes out. Until then,. you can [follow the docs and use mercurius instead](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/quick-start#mercurius-integration).

Your other option would be to downgrade to `@nestjs/common@^8` and `@nestjs/platform-fastify@^8` along with `@nestjs/graphql@^9` which supports `fastify@^3`

Comment: Just those modules? I changed the versions but now I get this error: The types returned by 'applyVersionFilter(...)' are incompatible between these types.
        Type 'VersionedRoute' is not assignable to type '(req: any, res: any, next: () => void) => Function'.
          Type 'VersionedRoute' provides no match for the signature '(req: any, res: any, next: () => void): Function'

Comment: Does it matter if I use apollo on the front end? Can apollo in the front end and mercurius mix?

Comment: If you downgrade to nest v8 you should downgrade everything together. Core, Common, platform-fastify, jwt, passport, typeorm, graphql, whatever else I may be forgetting.

Comment: As for using mercurius with apollo on the front, I _think_ that's posible, mercurius is a graphql engine and apollo on the front end is a way to format your queries in a way that's compliant with the gql spec, as far as I understand. It's really just a different server on the backend, just like if it was written in C# or Java